# PHP & MySQL Join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, group-by

I'm relatively new to coding in general, first year CS student and all of that.  I'm using PHP to display a list of school classes categories and a list of assignment posts within each category.  The desired output would be something like this:

```
CATEGORY 1
-Assign Post 1
-Assign Post 2

CATEGORY 2
-Assign Post 0
```

Using join gives me partial functionality, because it gets all the assign posts, but when I loop through and post the data it posts the Category title more than once.  I then tried using group_by but it's only posting one post per category.

I'm not gonna post all my code, simply the db queries.  I'll happily post the other code if you think the problem may be there.

```
//Select our classes, and get assignments from each class
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('categories');
$this->db->join('assignments', 'categories.cat_id = assignments.assign_cat_id');
$this->db->group_by("cat_id"); 

//Return the classes and assignments in an array
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Not to tricky right?  Any help is of course appreciated :).

**UPDATE**

I have figured out that group_concat will post the assignment names, and then I can explode the results.  Is this the only way, or is there a way to get it to post in a nice friendly array.  The only reason I ask is I feel this adds un-necessary code in my view file, where I'm exploding the data.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the return array look like?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get what you want just using SQL. Why don't you do the exploding in your model and return a nice friendly array to your view?

Comment: the better technique is that get all data whatever you need by query return it in an array and simply loop through each array index to display no need to do other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use group by ...use sort by Category id and while showing/or preparing array of data you can club records as per category..you cant achive this by single SQL

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the comments above.  With this I've sort of taken this in a different direction, but it's still fairly clean code.